# Beginner - Guessing Game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, number-guessing-game

In the past few days i have started to learn python 3 in my spare time and i am really enjoying it so far.

I have attempted many simple programs such as a palindrome checker and reverse a string in an attempt to improve my skills.

I was hoping that someone would be able to provide some feedback on the following program which is a guessing game program. The user is able to choose the number of guesses and the max possible value.

From my own perspective i think that possibly i am relying too much on while loops and if/else statements. Also i am not sure if my comments are sufficient, do they lack detail? 
Also i use parentheses around the conditionals in my if/else statements and in my while loops as i find it easier to read the condition this way. Is this a bad idea? Could it confuse people who are trying to read my code?

```
# In this program, the user must try to guess a random number generated by the computer
from random import randint

def guess_game():
    replay = 1   
    #Replay allows a user to replay the game without having to call the function again. 
    #The values are: 1 = Replay, any other character = End program
    while (replay == 1):       
        #lives = Number of chances you have to correctly guess the answer before the program finishes
        lives = int( input("How many lives would you like? ") )
        #max_value = upper bound for the randomly generated number. Starts at 0
        max_value = int( input("Please choose the largest number that can be generated: ") )
        random = randint(0, max_value)  #Generates a random int between 0 and max_value
        num_of_guesses = 1  #keeps track of the number of guesses made by the user
        while (num_of_guesses <= lives):
            guess = int( input("Please enter your guess: ") )
            if (guess == random):
                print("Good guess, that is correct! You got the right answer on guess number", num_of_guesses, ", well done!\n")
                break  #if answer is correct this will exit the while loop
            else:
                print("Unlucky, that guess was incorrect. You have", (lives-num_of_guesses), "lives remaining.\n")
            num_of_guesses = num_of_guesses + 1
        if (num_of_guesses > lives):
            print("You have run out of guesses. The correct answer was:", random)
        replay = int( input("\nWould you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other character for no: ") )
        if (replay != 1):
            print("Thank you for playing. See you next time")

guess_game()
```

Comment: you are incrementing an int in a loop until it reaches a given number. you can simplify that by using a `for` loop. in your case, `for num_of_guesses in range(1, lives + 1):`

Comment: avoid naming variables like keyword or packages. in your case, avoid naming a variable `random`. instead, something descriptive of its purpose, maybe `value_to_guess`.

Comment: you could extract the whole `replay` part in another function. it is not strictly part of the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Functions

Everything is in one function. You should stick to the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Basically, a function should have one job.

In a way, that does mean your whole game should be in the function, but it'd be better to have parts of it separated out. For example, getting an `int` from the user could be a function:

```
def get_int(message)
    return int(input(message))


lives = get_int("How many lives would you like? ")
max_value = get_int("Please choose the largest number that can be generated: ")
```

Now this may seem unnecessary, but now you could add input validation. Caridorc pointed out a bug, so you should do error handling. The best way to do this in Python is to catch any `ValueError`s that get thrown.

```
    try:
        return int(input(message))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer only")
```

Now the code wont crash when an invalid string is entered, but it also wont return a value. So you want to loop over this with `while` until a valid number is entered and `return`ed, ending your loop. This is how it would look:

```
def get_int(message)
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer only")
```

Now you have error handling set up, but you can still use one line to get each value:

```
lives = get_int("How many lives would you like? ")
max_value = get_int("Please choose the largest number that can be generated: ")
```

## Pythonic style

While we're on `while`, there's a more Pythonic way to do your main game loop. Instead of using `replay`, just use another infinite loop with `while True` and end your loop with a `break`, like this:

```
if replay != 1:
    print("Thank you for playing. See you next time")
    break
```

Also you don't need brackets around the condition, Python looks nicer without them and evaluates it just fine.

Instead of using

```
num_of_guesses = num_of_guesses + 1
```

use Python's `+=` operator:

```
num_of_guesses += 1
```

In fact, instead of that at all, you could just use a for loop instead of a `while` loop here:

```
for num_of_guesses in range(1, lives + 1):
    guess = get_int("Please enter your guess: ")
    if guess == random:
        print("Good guess, that is correct! You got the right answer on guess number", num_of_guesses, ", well done!\n")
        break  #if answer is correct this will exit the while loop
    else:
        print("Unlucky, that guess was incorrect. You have", (lives - num_of_guesses), "lives remaining.\n")
if num_of_guesses > lives:
    print("You have run out of guesses. The correct answer was:", random)
```

`range` lets you just loop over a list of numbers. In this case, it loops from one up to `lives`. Range will iterate up to but not include the second parameter, which means if you pass `lives + 1` the last loop will be on the value of `lives`.

You could also make use of Python's `else` clause for `for` loops. An `else` after a `for` loop in Python will be executed if the loop fully runs it's course without reaching a `break` command. If `break` gets called then the `else` block is skipped. This works perfect for your case, so I'd write it like this:

```
for num_of_guesses in range(1, lives + 1):
    guess = get_int("Please enter your guess: ")
    if guess == random:
        print("Good guess, that is correct! You got the right answer on guess number", num_of_guesses, ", well done!\n")
        break  #if answer is correct this will exit the while loop
    else:
        print("Unlucky, that guess was incorrect. You have", (lives - num_of_guesses), "lives remaining.\n")
else:
    print("You have run out of guesses. The correct answer was:", random)
```

## Readability

You have good names here. They're clear and readable, without being too long or overlapping. Although, I would advise against using `random` as a variable name. It doesn't cause a clash here since you used `from random import randint`, but it causes mild confusion. Something like `answer` would actually be more useful for indicating what the number is for.

However you have a lot of comments that don't need to be here. For example:

```
        break  #if answer is correct this will exit the while loop
```

This is quite a verbose comment. At most I would have `# Correct answer`. People reading this code probably know how `break` works. Your comments should focus on intent and abstract meaning. Python programmers can read your code and know what each part does, but *why* it does it, and what you want to do that for are useful to know in comment form. (as a beginner, perhaps you want to remind yourself of what these things do. This may be of benefit to start with, but I suggest reducing them as soon as you feel comfortable with it).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Python :)

**Readability**

Firstly, Python doesn't require parentheses (`(..)`) around conditionals. So you can just say:

```
while replay == 1:
```

Secondly, too many comments make the code look messy and the reader learns to ignore them. Avoid commenting obvious code, for example:

```
random = randint(0, max_value)  #Generates a random int between 0 and max_value
```

The comment is unnecessary. The code is self-explanatory enough, and if the reader doesn't know what `randint` does, it's time he/she learns it by themselves anyway. Assume the reader knows the language.

Thirdly, logical separation of code into paragraphs greatly helps readability. A 'paragraph' should make a single 'point', and then you should have a blank line before the next paragraph.

**Handling unwelcome scenarios**

You should handle corner cases in your code.

> "Any fool can write code that a computer can understand.
>   Good programmers write code that humans can understand." Martin Fowler

For example, a possible corner case in your program is invalid user input. What happens when the user types 'bla' as a guessed number? A `ValueError` is raised and crashes your program. You can handle these situations using one of two approaches.

Preferable approach:

```
try:
    number = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print('Enter a valid integer.')
else:
    # ... rest of the code. runs if the try block succeeded.
```

Less preferable:

```
number = input()
if not isinstance(number, int):
    print('Enter a valid integer.')
else:
    # ... rest of the code
```

Even better, this could be put into a loop to allow the user to retry. It can even be made into a handy function!

```
def get_user_int(message='Type a number: '):
    while True:
        try:
            print(message)
            return int(input())  # breaks out of the loop
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a valid integer.')
```

Than you can safely use `get_user_int` anywhere in your code. You can pass into it a custom message.

**Result**

Combining everything I mentioned, here's a possible outcome:

```
# In this program, the user must try to guess a random number generated by the computer
from random import randint

def guess_game():
    replay = 1   
    # Replay allows a user to replay the game without having to call the function again. 
    # The values are: 1 = Replay, any other character = End
    while replay == 1:       
        lives = get_user_int("How many lives would you like? ")
        max_value = get_user_int("Please choose the largest number that can be generated: ")
        rand_num = randint(0, max_value)
        num_of_guesses = 1  #keeps track of the number of guesses made by the user

        while num_of_guesses <= lives:
            guess = get_user_int("Please enter your guess: ")
            if guess == rand_num:
                print("Good guess, that is correct! You got the right answer on guess number", num_of_guesses, ", well done!\n")
                break
            else:
                print("Unlucky, that guess was incorrect. You have", (lives-num_of_guesses), "lives remaining.\n")
            num_of_guesses += 1

        if num_of_guesses > lives:
            print("You have run out of guesses. The correct answer was:", rand_num)

        replay = int( input("\nWould you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other character for no: ") )
        if replay != 1:
            print("Thank you for playing. See you next time")


def get_user_int(message='Enter a number: '):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a valid number.')



guess_game()
```

Good luck :)

Comment: thank you for your detailed reply. Commenting is still something i am getting to grips with but your explanation about not needing to comment on self-explanatory code is very helpful. Validating user input is a great suggestion, thank you for the example function. i will definitely use it in the future

Answer (score 2):

#### Modularization

You may want to let the user play just one guessing game from another program (maybe a module that makes you chose and play your favourite game), the code also becomes simpler if you write a `guess_game` function that just plays the guessing game, like:

```
def guess_game():
    lives = int( input("How many lives would you like? ") )

    max_value = int( input("Please choose the largest number that can be generated: ") )
    random = randint(0, max_value)  
    num_of_guesses = 1  
    while (num_of_guesses <= lives):
        guess = int( input("Please enter your guess: ") )
        if (guess == random):
            print("Good guess, that is correct! You got the right answer on guess number", num_of_guesses, ", well done!\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Unlucky, that guess was incorrect. You have", (lives-num_of_guesses), "lives remaining.\n")
        num_of_guesses = num_of_guesses + 1
    if (num_of_guesses > lives):
        print("You have run out of guesses. The correct answer was:", random)
```

You may then call this function in a loop to allow the user to play again, being careful about fixing:

**A bug**

When you ask:

> Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other character for no:

The user thinks that entering a non-number is ok, but if I enter for example `n`:

```
Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other character for no: n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/riccardo/guess_name.py", line 29, in <module>
    guess_game()
  File "/home/riccardo/guess_name.py", line 25, in guess_game
    replay = int( input("\nWould you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other character for no: ") )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n'
```

As entering a non-number is valid, it should be handled without crashing.

**[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)**

Your `while` loop iterates a fixed number of times (when the break is not reached, at least), so I suggest using `range`, in general learning about Python built-ins will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: thank your for your reply. i had not spotted the bug when entering a non-number, i will alter this to:    Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other integer for no:

Comment: @php123 Your solution is valid, but it looks more straightforward to keep the input as a string

Answer (score 2):

**User input**

At the moment, if the user inputs an invalid number, a non-handled exception is thrown and your program stops. It could be a good idea to try to handle this. Because this can make your code a bit more complicated, it is probably an even better idea to write a function to handle this job. Something like :

```
def get_int_from_user(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid value")
```

**Duplicated logic**

In 2 different places (3 if you count the text in the prompt), you take into account the fact that `replay == 1` means "play again". It might be just as easy to have this used in a single place.

For instance,

```
while True:
    ...
    replay = get_int_from_user("\nWould you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other character for no: ")
    if (replay != 1):
        print("Thank you for playing. See you next time")
        break
```

**Style**

You don't need that many parenthesis in Python.

You have way too many comments explaining the obvious. If one reads youre code, he/she is expected to know what `break` does.

**Loops**

You are using a `while` loop to perform iterations but this can just as easily be done with `for` and `range`. Also, a quite unknown feature of Python is the fact that `for` accept an `else` block which is to be understood as a `nobreak`.

```
    for num_of_guesses in range(1, lives+1):
        guess = get_int_from_user("Please enter your guess: ")
        if guess == random:
            print("Good guess, that is correct! You got the right answer on guess number", num_of_guesses, ", well done!\n")
            break  #if answer is correct this will exit the while loop
        else:
            print("Unlucky, that guess was incorrect. You have", (lives-num_of_guesses), "lives remaining.\n")
    else: # nobreak
        print("You have run out of guesses. The correct answer was:", random)
```

**Organisation**

It could be a good idea to split your program into small functions. Such a function could be used to handle a single game and be called again and again on demand from a function traditionnally named `main`.

Then the call to the main function (or any code actually doing something (by opposition to just defining)) is usually behind an [if **name** == "**main**":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard.

**Final code**

Here the final version of the code:

```
# In this program, the user must try to guess a random number generated by the computer
from random import randint

def get_int_from_user(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid value")

def play_game():
    lives = get_int_from_user("How many lives would you like? ")
    max_value = get_int_from_user("Please choose the largest number that can be generated: ")
    random = randint(0, max_value)
    for num_of_guesses in range(1, lives+1):
        guess = get_int_from_user("Please enter your guess: ")
        if guess == random:
            print("Good guess, that is correct! You got the right answer on guess number", num_of_guesses, ", well done!\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Unlucky, that guess was incorrect. You have", (lives-num_of_guesses), "lives remaining.\n")
    else: # nobreak
        print("You have run out of guesses. The correct answer was:", random)


def main():
    while True:
        play_game()
        replay = get_int_from_user("\nWould you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other character for no: ")
        if replay != 1:
            print("Thank you for playing. See you next time")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Further improvement**

It could be a good idea to add proper documentation like docstrings to your module and functions.